# execcommand not working in opera

Tags: opera, execcommand

i have this code, execcommand for BOLD, and it is not working under opera. anybody have some idea why ? thanks

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

 function SetToBold () {
        Editor.execCommand ('bold', false, null);
    }


 function start() {

    frames.iView.document.designMode = "On";

    var myIFrame = document.getElementById("iView");
    browser = navigator.appName;


    if (document.all) {  //IE
      var iframe_window = window.frames["iView"];
      iframe_window.document.body.focus();
    }
    else {  //Firefox
      field = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      setTimeout("field.focus()",250);
    }   


    if (browser == "Netscape") {  
      Editor = myIFrame.contentWindow.document;
      Editor.designMode = 'On';
      Editor.body.contentEditable = 'true';
    }

    else if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")  {  
      frames['iView'].document.designMode='On';
      Editor = frames['iView'].document;
    }


}
```

i call start function with body onload.  it is ok firefox and ie, but doesnt work in opera. 
   anybody knows about some restrictions of execcommand in opera ? thanks

Comment: It's likely your browser sniffing is failing here. Opera is neither "Netscape" nor "Microsoft Internet Explorer".... navigator.appName == "Opera" in Opera, so you've not turned on designMode for Opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the quoted script, the variable "Editor" is given a value only inside the browser sniffing section. In Opera "Editor" will be undefined and hence trying to do "Editor.execCommand()" will throw an error.

Rather than

```
if (browser == "Netscape") {  
  Editor = myIFrame.contentWindow.document;
  Editor.designMode = 'On';
  Editor.body.co`enter code here`ntentEditable = 'true';
}

else if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")  {  
  frames['iView'].document.designMode='On';
  Editor = frames['iView'].document;
}
```

you should drop the browser sniffing and do something like

```
if ( myIFrame && myIFrame.contentWindow ) {  
  Editor = myIFrame.contentWindow.document;
  Editor.designMode = 'On';
}
else if( frames['iView'] )  {  
  frames['iView'].document.designMode='On';
  Editor = frames['iView'].document;
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

before giving an answer I want to be sure about what you are asking. The script is testing Netscape or IE. Opening [dragonfly](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/) console, you can discover the values of your script. I have the feeling you will have difficulties with Webkit too.

```
>>> var browser = navigator.appName
undefined
>>> browser
"Opera"
```

Comment: navigator.appName evaluates to "Netscape" in WebKit browsers too :/

Comment: hehe webkit shadowing itself.

Answer (score 0):

ive noted that the newer versions of opera appear as NETSCAPE when you ask for it with navigator.appName. i remember that was not always so because i also got some older "ifs" around my source where i used the regular name. cant say since when this is, just saying.